# Assigning dynamic attribute list to another class

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

I have `Person` class with the following attributes:

```
Person.attribute_names
# => ["id", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "age", "address_1", "address_2", 
#  "city", "state", "country", "is_active", "created_at", "updated_at"]
```

I have another class `PersonFacade`, which should hold exactly the same attributes. I have this code:

```
class PersonFacade
  attr_list = Person.attribute_names
  attr_reader *attr_list

  def initialize(p_object)
     #p_object.attributes.slice(*Person.attribute_names)
     # Line above is giving me the attributes, but I don't want to manually assign them.
  end
end
```

How can I assign `Person` attributes to `PersonFacade` attributes?

Comment: Consider `cloning` the object so that attributes are also copied to the new object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class PersonFacade
  attr_reader *Person.attribute_names

  def initialize(p)
    p.attributes.each { |k,v| self.instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider extending PersonFacade from Person. This makes attributes of Person available in PersonFacade easily.

```
class Person
   @id=nil
   @first_name=nil

   def initialize(id, first_name)
      @id = id
      @first_name = first_name
    end

    attr_accessor :id, :first_name
end

class PersonFacade < Person
end

p = PersonFacade.new(1,"Harry")
print p.first_name
```